# Best way to store messages (native + app2app)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I want to develop a messaging app which will show messages from native content provider (sms uri ) and messages that has been sent from my app.
I am stuck while managing this messages.I have tried below idea but plese do suggest which is the best .

Here is the observer code I have used:

```
public class MyObserver extends ContentObserver {
    public MyObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        Log.e("uri","change");
        this.onChange(selfChange, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
        // do s.th.
        // depending on the handler you might be on the UI
        // thread, so be cautious!
        Log.e("uri",""+uri.toString());
    }
}

Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(uri,true,new MyObserver(new Handler()));
```

1.I have saved all native and A2A messages in databases so it was easy to show but I got problem while synching native message gets delete as there is not broadcast listener for message deletion.

2.Second option is two save only a2a message in database but it is complex to and time consuming to get messages from two different places (database and content provider and manage the to show view like inbox)

3.Third is to save all app to app messages in content provider with custom message type.and show all messages from content provider only .

Please guide me on this.

Comment: for 1. you can use ContentObserver with ContentProvider to detect SMS deletion.

Comment: @GaurawYadav hi thank for replying but I tried to implement observer but it doesn't get called when message gets delete.

Comment: please post the code.

Comment: @GaurawYadav have updated the code

Comment: Use content://mms-sms/conversations as uri and see if it helps you.